# Doing a SetLength on an array passed into a proc by reference

Tags: delphi

Sure, even I can do this...

```
var
  testarray : array of string;

setlength(testarray, 5);
```

but if I want to get clever and have a procedure into which I pass the array by referance like this I cant do it!

```
procedure DoStuffWithArray(var passedarray : array of string);
begin
  setlength(passedarray, 5);
end;
```

compiler says 'incompatible types' on the single line of code in my proc.

I can do other stuff on the array like set set element values if i do a setlength before i call the proc, but I cannot do the setlength in my proc, which is what I want to do.

Any help much appreciated, thanks all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Array types as parameters need to have a name.  So:

```
type TStringArray = array of string;
procedure DoStuffWithArray(var passedarray: TStringArray);
```

Then it would work.

But if you need a dynamically-sized group of strings, you'd probably find a TStringList easier to use anyway.

Comment: @Csharpdefetor - If you like Mason's answer (which is a good one) then you ought to accept it.  You will get rep bonus too.

Comment: This is due to historical quirk in Delphi's syntax, in that it uses the same syntax for open array parameters. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112729/biggest-delphi-nitpicks/2113650#2113650

Comment: You also can reuse `TStringDynArray` from `System.Types`